# Text adjustment in button under scrollbars in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm working on scrollView.i have created 20 buttons under Linear Layout inside ScrollView. Now I'm writing the text inside button, I used  android:padding_centre-verticle="1dp", but it's fetching warning massage that it can be used only above api level 26.I have to write text inside button centre. Is there other solution.
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to center the text in the button itself? What exactly are you trying to adjust?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gravity="center_vertical"`

Make sure your are not using `layout_gravity`